# How to switch between two different threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, ros, ros2

I am working with the serial communication in ROS. I had been using C++ till now but need to port my code to `python` as my other module APIs in python. I had successfully created a publisher and subscriber npde but as i am working with serial, i can either write or read at the same time? so i decided to make two different thread for my system, one run for reading a data and one is used for sending data. Everything works fine for the first time but when the data comes in again, the second thread is not ending and in the infinite loop so i can receive data but the incoming data from topic is not send via modem with writing thread.

Could anyone please take a look at this to find out why program stuck at receiving thread ?
P.S. : You may not be able to run the code as this need actual modem to be connected to your system.

```py
#subscriber_node.py
 
import threading
import sys
import time

from time import sleep
from queue import Queue, Empty

# The main ROS Python client library
import rclpy # Import the ROS client library for Python

# The main node class which will be used to create custom nodes
from rclpy.node import Node # Enables the use of rclpy's Node class

# This is for standard message types when defining publishers
from std_msgs.msg import String 

# This is whoi python APIs.
from py_whoi.micromodem import *
from py_whoi.messageparams import *
from py_whoi.messageparser import *
from py_whoi.unifiedlog import UnifiedLog

# Open a connection to modem
# unilog = UnifiedLog(console_log_level='INFO')

modem_a = Micromodem(name="MM2")#, unified_log=unilog )
modem_serial_port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"  
modem_baudrate = 19200
modem_source_id = 0
modem_dest_id = 1
modem_a.connect(modem_serial_port, modem_baudrate)

mutex = threading.Lock()

class WHOISubscriber(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("whoi_sub_node")

        # Create subscriber(s)    
     
        # The node subscribes to messages of type std_msgs/Float64MultiArray, over a topic named:
        #   /object_msg
        # The callback function is called as soon as a message is received.
        # The maximum number of queued messages is 10.
        self.subscription_1 = self.create_subscription(
          String,
          '/object_msg',
          self.listener_callback,
          10)
        self.subscription_1  # prevent unused variable warning

        # Create publisher(s)  
         
        # This node publishes the position in robot frame coordinates.
        # The node publishes to messages of type std_msgs/Float64MultiArray, over a topic named:
        #   /pos_in_robot_base_frame
        # Maximum queue size of 10. 
        self.publisher_pos_robot_frame = self.create_publisher(String, '/pos_in_robot_base_frame', 10)
        timer_period = 3.0  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.publish_position)
        self.i = 0

       
        @property
        def is_connected(self):
            return self._serialport.isOpen()
       
         
    def publish_position(self):
        """
        Callback function.
        Publish Hello World message to the topic /pos_in_robot_base_frame
        for every 3 seconds. Change the message content accordingly.
        """
        # msg = Float64MultiArray() # Create a message of this type 
        msg = String() # Create a message of this type 
        msg.data = 'Hello World: %d from subscriber whoi.' % self.i # Store the object's position
        self.publisher_pos_robot_frame.publish(msg) # Publish the position to the topic 
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing publish_position: "%s"' % msg.data)
        self.i += 1

    def send_data(self, msg):
        """
        sender function.
        Function to send the data from the whoi modem using APIs. It takes the msg data coming from the topic
        /object_msg, prepare and send it to the modem. It uses the command "send" to send the data. i.e It uses
        the legacy packet method in which you need to tell the modem first the cycleinit and then send the data 
        which is in the hex format, which would send acoustically to the destination node  in the system.
        This serves as UDP packet. Sleep timer has been used to wait the time taken to send the data and actually decode
        received data.
        """
        try:
            # mutex.acquire(blocking=True)
            data_to_be_send = bytes(msg, 'utf-8')
            #modem_a.send_cycleinit((cycleinfo(src_id=0, dest_id=1, rate_num=0, ack=1, num_frames=1))
            modem_a.send_cycleinit(cycleinfo = CycleInfo(modem_source_id, modem_dest_id, 0, 1, 1)) # (src_id, dest_id, rate_num, ack, 1)
            sleep(1)
            # modem_a.send_frame(dataframe = DataFrame(src=0, dest=1, rate_num=0, ack=1, data=data_to_be_send))
            modem_a.send_frame(dataframe = DataFrame(modem_source_id, modem_dest_id, 0, 1, data_to_be_send))  
            sleep(1)
            self.get_logger().info('WHOI Modem sent data acoustically.')
            # mutex.release()
            print(data_to_be_send)
            
        except:                       
            modem_a.disconnect()
            self.get_logger().info('WHOI Modem disconnected after sending data in send data function.')
    

    def rec_data(self):
        """
        receiver function.
        Function to receive the data from the modem using APIs. It takes the msg data coming on the modem 
        acoustically in the newly created queue. It basically waits for the CARXD message from the modem. 
        Once it receives the CARXD message, it decodes the data and prints the data.
        i.e It uses the acomms micromodem class. 
        """
        # modem_a = Micromodem(name="MM2")
        # modem_a.connect(modem_serial_port, modem_baudrate)

        try:
            """"This will create a new queue for Rx messages on micromodem and attach a new queue with
            existing attach_incoming_msg_queue function and print the new incoming messages from new queue."
            """
            # mutex.acquire(blocking=True)
            modem_rx_queue = Queue()
            modem_a.attach_incoming_msg_queue(modem_rx_queue)
            while True:
                try:
                    """This will get the message from the queue and grab the first message and split the message in parts.
                    """
                    # if self._serialport.isOpen():
                    msg = modem_rx_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.1)
                    
                    msgParts = str(msg).split(',')  # Need to convert the message from list to string
                    msg_type = msgParts[0]
                    msg_params = msgParts[5:]
                    # ['params'] = msgParts[1:]
                    # ['raw'] = raw

                    # to check if the message is a valid message or not empty message
                    if msg_type=="$CARXD" and msg_params != None and len(msg_params) > 0:
                        # print(msg_params) # print the message parameters that contained the actual message in Hex
                        Incoming_Rx_data = (msg_params[0]).split('*')[0]
                        print(Incoming_Rx_data) # Actual message in Hex
                        # mutex.release()
                        # self.get_logger().info('WHOI Modem Received Data acoustically: %s' % Incoming_Rx_data)
                        self.get_logger().info('WHOI Modem Received Data acoustically:')
                        # print(type(Incoming_Rx_data)) 
                    else: # not connected
                        sleep(0.2) # Wait half a second, try again.                   
                        
                except Empty:
                    pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\n\nExiting")
            modem_a.disconnect()
            self.get_logger().info('WHOI Modem disconnected after receiving.')
            sys.exit(0)

    def listener_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info('I got: "%s" on /object_msg' % msg.data)
        self.get_logger().info("Received a data from /object_msg and preparing for sending same data acoustically.")
        

        # Finally creating thread
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.rec_data)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.send_data(str(msg.data)))

        # starting thread 1 - Comment this print statements if needed 
       
        t1.start()
        
        # t1.join()
        
        
        self.get_logger().info('thread 1 - receiving thread started.')

        # starting thread 2
        
        t2.start()
        
        self.get_logger().info('thread 2 - receiving thread started.')

        # wait until thread 1 is completely executed
        
        t1.join()
        
        
        self.get_logger().info('thread 1 - receiving thread joined.')
        
       
        t2.join()
       
        
        self.get_logger().info('thread 2 - sending thread joined.')


def main(args=None):
    # Initialise ROS client library
    # It can take commandline arguments or a context name
    # as input parameters, which we will not use currently.
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    my_sub = WHOISubscriber()

    print("[WHOI SUBSCRIBER] Waiting for data to be published over topic")

    try:
        # The `spin` function will keep the function from exiting (I assume
        # because it's all asyncronous now), until a KeyboardInterrupt.
        rclpy.spin(my_sub)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Kill the node
        my_sub.destroy_node()

        # Shutdown and disconnect the client library
        rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output**

```sh
[WHOI SUBSCRIBER] Waiting for data to be published over topic
[INFO] [1652791325.779022111] [whoi_sub_node]: Publishing publish_position: "Hello World: 0 from subscriber whoi."
[INFO] [1652791328.757283538] [whoi_sub_node]: Publishing publish_position: "Hello World: 1 from subscriber whoi."
[INFO] [1652791331.757229112] [whoi_sub_node]: Publishing publish_position: "Hello World: 2 from subscriber whoi."
[INFO] [1652791334.756775223] [whoi_sub_node]: Publishing publish_position: "Hello World: 3 from subscriber whoi."
[INFO] [1652791337.757394185] [whoi_sub_node]: Publishing publish_position: "Hello World: 4 from subscriber whoi."
[INFO] [1652791340.097852311] [whoi_sub_node]: I got: "WNrnTtogMFN04v2KOYJLiMzkCh6R" on /object_msg
[INFO] [1652791340.098774010] [whoi_sub_node]: Received a data from /object_msg and preparing for sending same data acoustically.
[INFO] [1652791344.104244151] [whoi_sub_node]: WHOI Modem sent data acoustically.
b'WNrnTtogMFN04v2KOYJLiMzkCh6R'
000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0FA55AFFEEDDCCBBAA90807060504055AF
[INFO] [1652791365.446508085] [whoi_sub_node]: WHOI Modem Received Data acoustically:
000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0FA55AFFEEDDCCBBAA90807060504055AF
[INFO] [1652791367.446508087] [whoi_sub_node]: WHOI Modem Received Data acoustically:
[INFO] [1652791381.305565989] [whoi_sub_node]: thread 1 - receiving thread started.
[INFO] [1652791381.306729773] [whoi_sub_node]: thread 2 - receiving thread started.
[INFO] [1652791381.307589789] [whoi_sub_node]: thread 1 - receiving thread joined.
[INFO] [1652791381.308452921] [whoi_sub_node]: thread 2 - sending thread joined.
[INFO] [1652791381.309906606] [whoi_sub_node]: Publishing publish_position: "Hello World: 5 from subscriber whoi."
[INFO] [1652791381.311024559] [whoi_sub_node]: I got: "tewPB8BW0x8uNScphIzfu9Mpokhc" on /object_msg
[INFO] [1652791381.311877118] [whoi_sub_node]: Received a data from /object_msg and preparing for sending same data acoustically.
[INFO] [1652791385.317304354] [whoi_sub_node]: WHOI Modem sent data acoustically.
b'tewPB8BW0x8uNScphIzfu9Mpokhc'
000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0FA55AFFEEDDCCBBAA90807060504055AF
[INFO] [1652791404.073748634] [whoi_sub_node]: WHOI Modem Received Data acoustically:
000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0FA55AFFEEDDCCBBAA90807060504055AF
[INFO] [1652791418.337479476] [whoi_sub_node]: thread 1 - receiving thread started.
[INFO] [1652791418.338659823] [whoi_sub_node]: thread 2 - receiving thread started.
[INFO] [1652791418.339525429] [whoi_sub_node]: thread 1 - receiving thread joined.
[INFO] [1652791418.340388951] [whoi_sub_node]: thread 2 - sending thread joined.
[INFO] [1652791418.341853726] [whoi_sub_node]: Publishing publish_position: "Hello World: 6 from subscriber whoi."
[INFO] [1652791418.342981213] [whoi_sub_node]: I got: "ofUMyED0BbPfueF64VsHy3vFCrKd" on /object_msg
[INFO] [1652791418.343844862] [whoi_sub_node]: Received a data from /object_msg and preparing for sending same data acoustically.
[INFO] [1652791422.349254465] [whoi_sub_node]: WHOI Modem sent data acoustically.
b'ofUMyED0BbPfueF64VsHy3vFCrKd'
000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0FA55AFFEEDDCCBBAA90807060504055AF
[INFO] [1652791464.332005914] [whoi_sub_node]: WHOI Modem Received Data acoustically:
```

Comment: Having separate threads for reading and writing to a serial interface isn’t really optimal since you can(and will) run into concurrency issues. I would suggest having 1 thread for all I/O

Comment: BTables is right. You should not seperate your serial handler. Not sure what py_whoi is but  usually you would use pythons serial module. Where does DataFrame() come from ? Do you really have a modem ? really you should reduce your code to the problematic part !

Comment: @user3732793 : i am working with the modem and the dataframe comes from the actual modem as a sensor data.

Comment: @JayPatel interesting setup. But as mentioned do not seperate the serial handler for read and write on serial to different threads as in one loop in a node and do the sensor stuff in an other one.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you shouldn't pass `self.send_data(str(msg.data))) in here because the thread will run` None`

```
# Finally creating thread
t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.rec_data)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.send_data(str(msg.data)))
```

type this instead

```
t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.send_data, args=(str(msg.data),))
```

Comment: It didn't solve the issue. The thread still didn't pass back to writing side.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using separate threads, you can use timers with MultiThreadedExecutor. Maybe you can control when you want to send/receive data using a bool.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).